# PHP register function not inserting into phpmyadmin table properly

Tags: php, mysql

My registration on my website does not seem to be inserting the registration details of users into the database correctly. The table consists of 2 fields (ID & PASSWORD, ID being a 9 digit int). When ever i enter in a ID and PASSWORD, in my table it shows up as a single digit number and will increment by 1 everytime i enter another record via my registration form. It essentially resets the ID i inserted through the form to a incremental number.

Below is my code:

```
<?php

$host="********"; // Host name 
$username="******"; // Mysql username 
$password="*********"; // Mysql password 
$db_name="arihealthinfo"; // Database name 
$tbl_name="USERS"; // Table name 

// Connect to server and select databse.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

// username and password sent from form
$ParticipantID=$_POST["ParticipantID"];
$password=$_POST["UserPass"];

$sql = "INSERT INTO USERS (ID, PASSWORD) VALUES ('$participantID', '$password')"; 
mysql_query($sql);
echo "Thank you for registering, you can now login:";
?>
<a href= http://www.arihealth.info/index.php>Login Page.</a>
<?php

?>
```

Comment: Do you have a primary key field besides that ID?

Comment: if(! mysql_query($sql) )
   {
      die('Could not enter data: ' . mysql_error());
   } try this

Comment: no, ID is set to primary key at the moment. @WilliamMadede

Comment: Consider using mysqli or pdo.

Comment: Please make sure you set the length of the column ID to 10 or so, if it is not set up like that.

Comment: I did as you said, but no luck. I cleared the database and tried entering 3 new records with 9 digit ID's, but it just made the ID's 1,2,3 and only the PASSWORD remained as i entered it in the form. @WilliamMadede

Comment: Okay, lets start again, the ID column is not set as a primary key right? and it is not on Auto-Increment right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`PASSWORD` is a reserved mysql keyword.

Try using this query instead with using backticks

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `USERS` (`ID`, `PASSWORD`) VALUES ('$participantID', '$password')";
```

and it should work like expected.

**Edit:** The answer is simple, my bad on the keyword thing and not being able to comment yet on questions.

You made a typo:

```
$ParticipantID=$_POST["ParticipantID"];

$sql = "INSERT INTO USERS (ID, PASSWORD) VALUES ('$participantID', '$password')";
```

See the capital P on the variable?

Comment: No because there is no **R** in password https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/keywords.html

Comment: The password is not the issue here, please use the comment box if you are just suggesting what might work...done

Comment: Post edited with the right answer, i tried to add comment but not enough rep yet. thanks for pointing out @WilliamMadede